# Is there a command to print the steps a function is using in Python?

Tags: python

I'm working on doolittle decomposition. My function is fine(no errors), but i'm not receiving the right results. I'm sure everything is fine in the function with the exception of 2-4 variables that I might be misplacing. So my doubt here is if there is a function or a command to print all the calculations this function is using, step by step, so I can understand what is going wrong.

I'm using Python 3.6.2, Geany, Windows 10.

Here's the code:

```
def doolittle(A):
n = len(A)
b = 0
c = 0
L = [[0.0] * n for s in range(n)]
U = [[0.0] * n for s in range(n)]
for k in range(n):
    L[k][k] = 1.0
    for j in range(n):
        b += L[k][j] * U[j][k]
        U[k][j] = A[k][j] - b
    for i in range(k+1,n):
        c += L[k][i] * U[i][k]
        L[k][j] = (A[k][j] - c)/U[k][k]
return(L,U)

A = [[1, -3, 2], [-2,8,-1], [4, -6, 5]]
print(doolittle(A))
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
import ipdb
ipdb.set_trace()
```

Try using this where u want to enter the function.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely what I was looking for. But it did raise 2 more questions.

1 - Can I do this debug with the numbers in the variables? It does loop for the 'fors' I'm using, but it does not show the number the variable is taking, so it is a little obscure for me, since my main problem is to see exactly where the algorithm is getting some equation wrong.

2 - How can I do it with the function? I used ipdb.set_trace() and it debug the script, ignoring the function. I'd like to do the script with the function together, so I don't have to undo the function everytime I debug.

Comment: You can use c if you want to go to the next function and n if you want to go to the next line in the function. Moreover, if its for a function then after you enter the function you can put this ipdb.set_trace().